# How can I prove that there's a unique solution to $3^x - 2^y = 17$?

Tags: number-theory

The solution to $3^x - 2^y = 17$ is $(x,y)=(4,6)$ - easily found with probing. How can I prove that no other solutions exist?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that $x,y$ were supposed to be integers.

Answer (score 1):

This is Pillai's equation $a^x −b^y =c$. In [this paper](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/paper19.pdf),

**Theorem $1.1$** : If $a, b$ and $c$ are nonzero integers with $a,b\ge 2$, then equation $a^x-b^y=c$ has at most two solutions in positive integers $x$ and $y$.

Especially, **Theorem $1.5$** says that we have at most $1$ solution in our case ($a=3,b=2,c=17$). Hence, we can see that $(x,y)=(4,6)$ is the only solution.

Comment: @CsabaOkrona: You are welcome.